# Is MVVM for client and MVC for server acceptable?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, mvvm, client-server

I'm working on a client/server model for a university project using .NET and on the client I'm using MVVM but for server I was thinking of using a Database First approach with Entity Framework which is MVC. Will it cause any issues if they follow different architecture patterns?

Comment: you can use Angular [MVVM] on the client side and MVC / Web Api for your services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.It will not.
And most of the times we have to use different patterns for clients and server.Because the complexity, functionality, technology stack and etc of the client and server are different we have to choose the architecture pattern suitable for each by considering those facts.